# Is there any example where a country completely dropped its historical or traditional ally?

Tags: international-relations, history

Is there any example where a country completely changed its historical or traditional ally peacefully?

As an analogy, we know Turkey and Pakistan are traditional allies. Let's say India awards Turkey a $4 billion arms contract. Therefore, Turkey abandons Pakistan and becomes an Indian ally. Like this...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "these kinds of changes". Do you mean without change in government? Most transitions in Eastern Europe were peaceful IIRC. (And yeah, change in government is a common way by which foreign policy changes. "Diplomatic process" is rather meaningless/NA in terms of internal changes in a country.)

Comment: @Fizz, *Do you mean without change in government?* --- Kind of, Yes. However, it is hard to express what I am trying to understand. For example, Turkey and Pakistan are allies. Say India awards Turkey a $4 billion arms contract. Therefore, Turkey abandons Pakistan and became an Indian ally. Like this...

Comment: Aye, it is not clear what 'traditional ally' is supposed to mean exactly here. Most transitions from big powers having colonies and waging war with each other to more independent states did not happen much longer than 100 years ago...

Comment: Egypt has changed its orientation from Soviet ally to an American one, signing a peace treaty with Israel in the process. More recently, all kinds of *pivots* practiced by the US presidents also fall in this category, although the changes may be less drastic (hard to quantify though.)

Comment: @RogerVadim, Yes. This is correct. Although Egypt hasn't totally severed its military relations with Russia.

Comment: @user366312 I think it is difficult to find the cases of 100% loyalty to one of the two camps, except in war. Even these days, though Europe aligned with the US, most European countries continue relations with Russia... even US continues, if we look at Nickel imports or space flights.

Comment: Perhaps another example could be the US normalization with China by Nixon&Kissinger (though warming up started before them). Especially if we look at how big a trade exists between the US and China nowadays.

Comment: *Warsaw-pact countries changed their orientation from the USSR/Russia to NATO. Some countries in South America changed their orientations from the West to the USSR. Recently, Mali changed its orientation from the West to Russia. I am not talking about these kinds of changes.* Why are you ruling these out? Please explain what you want or don't want so we can attempt to answer your question.

Comment: What does peacefully mean in this context? Without a war, or without anybody get killed?

Comment: @convert, *What does peacefully mean in this context? Without a war, or without anybody get killed?* --- Yes.

Comment: Sorry, what tha yes was refering to? For example in Romania the leader got executed, does it still count as peacefully?

Comment: @convert, *For example in Romania the leader got executed, does it still count as peacefully?* --- No. The OP even has an example.

Answer (score 4):

Czarist Russia switched from the [Three Emperors' League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_the_Three_Emperors) to the [Triple Entente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Entente).

Japan was allied with the British during and immediately after [WWI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_during_World_War_I), then reoriented towards Germany before WWII, so it was not changing allies during wartime. But their policy was expansionistic, so it might not count for your question.

Finland switched from genuine neutrality (and trade with both sides) to EU membership.

Comment: Also Italy around WWI, but not sure if it was without changes in gov't. Also it's debatable how natural their alliance with Austria-Hungary was to begin with https://www.theworldwar.org/learn/about-wwi/italy-enters-world-war-i

Comment: @Fizz But even if there were changes in gov't, as long the changes were peceful should count as answer.

Comment: Germany refused to prolong Three Emperors' League treaty, so it was long dead befor Russia switched to Triple Entente.

Comment: Actually, the British dropped their alliance with Japan in favour of good relations with the USA in the 1920s, well before Japan started to align with Germany. That alignment came quite late: Germany was providing military support to China until Hitler stopped that in 1937.

Answer (score 4):

**Soviet Union - Nazi Germany**

Soviet Union was initially in good terms with Nazi Germany, signed the famous Molotov–Ribbentrop Pact dividing the Europe peacefully. In 1939, the Soviet Union joined Nazi Germany as a de facto ally, and the two powers invaded Poland together. Nazi speeches were reprinted in the Soviet press and Nazi officers admired Soviet efficiency in mass deportations ([source, The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/05/19/opinion/russia-fascism-ukraine-putin.html?unlocked_article_code=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACEIPuonUktbfqYhkTVUaCibSRdkhrxqAwuLS26c9jzrwJTOeSC1HivkWGYGB_UqIfbd_Zt113yieQJUJFo4Tc8FI770VOV1xGU7vq4GYmZ8BLmJu847jBm9s1deTBuE0tGKwYmL8eL50m_jn4B-MbDHpXaCL1XAxNU0y98seAFKp2HUCx6fAFe5niJIpjbp6WMcMFXpXbzKKvvLoFx18JNyDCxnW4QU3UO1aMirByZ_es_lTNVUPVi-VCS938m0-69hDONoIP66ZLx8ofMD2hb15GXVBsZgGcrcxQ4mkCxkxc8Uf)).

This changed after A.Hitler attacked the Soviet Union.

Comment: I downvoted because historical facts say otherwise - Stalin was always wary of Hitler and reached out many times to other European powers to contain Hitler. But they ignored him and played their own geopolitics because they knew Hitler wasn't a fan of the Russians. This created a situation where Russia was pushed towards Hitler and hence the temporary alliance.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously it's incorrect to claim that the Warsaw pact nations switched their alliance by any means other than peaceful.  After their governments changed from the Soviet colonial governments to governments with allegiance to the countries they governed, they joined the NATO alliance, aimed at stopping Russia's colonial conquest, as was always NATO's goal.  This change of allegiance did not involve any war against Russia, the colonial power.

Comment: Sure there were no war with Russia for independance, but pro Soviet governments were overthrown and in some examples really bloody.

Comment: I understand the eagerness, but 'colonial' is not a correct term regarding Warsaw Pact.

Comment: @alamar the modern view on that is changing to mean exactly that. I don't really feel like arguing this point other than to say that it's the zeitgeist now outside of the hardcore Communist circles.  And, of course, outside of the hardcore Russia-never-does-anything-wrong circles, but the latter is to be expected.

Comment: @convert Transitions were peaceful in most of Eastern Europe except in Romania which did have a brief uprising against the communist leadership. Czechoslovakia, East Germany, Poland, Hungary, and others were done without any kind of coup or civil war.

Comment: @Stuart F Romania was exactly the bloody example.

Answer (score 2):

As a result of Egyptian president Anwar Sadat's economic policy of "opening the door" to private investment in Egypt there was a break with longtime ally and aid-giver the USSR - replaced by the United States.

An other example is Albania. Albania’s alliance with the USSR steadily eroded and collapsed altogether by the early 1960s as a result of the campaign of de-Stalinization launched by Soviet leader Nikita Khrushchev. The PRC under Mao Zedong emerged as the new patron for the country.

Answer (score 0):

Before the outbreak of the First World War, Italy belonged to the so-called Triple Alliance with Austria-Hungary and the German Reich. In 1914 the country refused to join the war on the side of the Central Powers on the grounds that the Triple Alliance was a defensive pact. In 1915 Italy joined the Entente. Italy's switch to the side of the Entente powers was linked by them with far-reaching territorial promises at the expense of Austria-Hungary.

Answer (score -1):

The United States of America - [France aided the Americans](https://www.battlefields.org/learn/articles/france-american-revolution) in its fight against the British, and is often considered as its first international ally. But later, [the US totally pivoted to the UK](https://www.livescience.com/when-did-uk-us-become-allies.html) as its most trusted ally in Europe.

Comment: The United States did not have any alliances during the 19th century.  It's alliances with France during the 18th century ended after accomplishing its goal (the independence of the US from Britain).